# Missing facebook Library in android

Tags: android, facebook

```
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
```

Anybody help me with this?  Where can I find facebook library or I have only facebook-Android-sdk. How can I import this library?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Facebook Android SDK [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385/). Import the Facebook folder in the zip into your workspace using the import project wizard. Then right click on your own project and go properties and then select Android. At the bottom you will see a add button click this and then select the Facebook project you imported into your workspace.